# Laravel billable get records where subscription not ended

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel Billable and I've got this hooked up to a different model (Client) and all works fine. However, I'm trying to fetch all records on a model where the subscription end date is null. I'm doing the following;

```php
$collection = Model::where('client.subscriptions', function ($q) {
    $q->where('ends_at', NULL);
})->get();
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "client"
>   LINE 1: select * from "table" where "client"."subscriptions" =... ^
>   (SQL: select * from "table" where "client"."subscriptions" = (select *
>   where "ends_at" is null))

## Update

Code Update

```
   $jobs = \App\Models\Job::with(['client' => function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query){
        $query->where('ends_at', NULL);
    });
}])->get();
```

Example Database

```
(model) Job (db:name = 'jobs')

id | client_id | name

(model) Client (db:name = 'clients')

id | name 

(model) Subscription (db:name = 'subscriptions')

id | client_id | stripe_plan | trial_ends_at | ends_at
```

Client Model

```
/**
 * Get all of the subscriptions for the Stripe model.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function subscriptions()
{
   // foreign key is client_id
    return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class, $this->getForeignKey())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Job Model

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

Now using this query;

```
 $jobs = \App\Models\Job::with(['client' => function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query){
            $query->where('ends_at', NULL);
        });
    }])->get();
```

I still get the records where the subscription ends_at is not null. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query is;

```
$jobs = Job::whereHas('client', function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('subscriptions', function ($query) {
        $query->where('ends_at', NULL);
    });
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the base Model class defined in the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent namespace, I thing you are wrong.

You should use directly your model (from your question/code it seems to be called Client) and do something like this:

```php
$collection = Client::where('subscriptions', function ($q) {
    return $q->whereNull('ends_at');
})->get();
```